# Change colour of text in string?

Tags: php, html, css, colors

I would like to change the colour of some text in my email signup confirmation message.

An example string:

e.g `$mystring = 'Thank you for signing up!<br>Please visit mysite.com and log in.';`

Say i wanted to change the colour of the text after the `<br>`. How do I change the color of the text after the `<br>`?

Comment: I'd say `<font color='blue'>` but even I'd lynch me for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the according html tags. If you want to change the color of words inside text, you should use the span-tag. For bigger parts you should surround with a div-tag. For your example, you would write something like:

```
$mystring = 'Thank you for signing up!<br><span style="color: red;">Please visit mysite.com and log in.</span>';
```

Comment: Even better: give the element a class and apply the styling through CSS, this will make it easier to change in future.

Comment: I agree to James Donnelly, that would be the extended solution I would also choose. Guessing the level of the author of the question, I think that this would be to advanched for the beginning, that is why I suggest to use a span-tag. But definitely, you are right: classes are the way to go.

Comment: Interesting note on your choice of colour for your example: Paul Graham did some work on using Bayesian filters for Spam detection. In analysing the results while some patterns found to be a strong indicator of Spam were obvious like "opt-out", "viagra", "unsubscribe" and terms associated with pornography, it was also found that "FF0000" was as good an indicator of Spam as anything else, which is of course the hex-code for red. If it has red bits, it's almost certainly Spam.

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend using the `span` tag for this as others have recommended.

Of course, for web pages that's the way to go, but you want to use it in an e-mail. Sadly, simple CSS still does not work in every e-mail client. You should resort to the deprecated `font` tag:

```
$mystring = 'Thank you for signing up!<br><font color="red">Please visit mysite.com and log in.</font>';
```

This should work in every e-mail client that supports basic HTML formatting.

See also: http://www.reachcustomersonline.com/how-to-code-html-email-newsletters-all-new-version/#step4

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery !

```
var strings = $mystring;
strings = strings.replace(/\[Thank\syou\]/g, '[<font color="red">Thank you</font>]');
$('element').html(text);
```

Comment: The `font` element was [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#edef-FONT) in the HTML4 specification. You really shouldn't use that any more.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously.. :) You want to change text color with PHP? You can't do that. Just use HTML/CSS. 
If you don't have control over the HTML text, then here is something that might work for you:
You can try separating the string with "explode()".

```
$your_array = explode("<br>", 'Thank you for signing up!<br>Please visit mysite.com and log in.');
echo $your_array[0];
echo '<font color="#000000">'.$your_array[1].'</font>';
```

Otherwise, just do it with markup..

Answer (score 0):

You need use css. I think it would be better approach to do it by adding a css class in your html like this:

```
$mystring = "Thank you for signing up!<br><span class='my-class'>Please visit mysite.com and log in.</span>";
```

then in your css

```
.my-class{
 color: red;
 //set other style
}
```